# MagTek Card reader not working when processed in TChromium web browser

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, tchromium, cardreader

I am working with a 3rd party web service to process credit card payments.

When I swipe a credit card via google chrome the payment is detected and processed.

However when I attempt to swipe a credit card via the built in Delphi web browser TChromium, nothing happens.

Can't figure out why its not working are their any settings I need to set on the TChromium browser?

**Update**

I have verified that that the card reader reads and posts the data to whatever field/component is selected.

One difference I have found with Chrome and the TChromium web browser is that when I process a card in the TChromium web browser it automatically tabs to the next html component after processing the card.. Where this does not happen in Chrome it just stays with the current field/component selected.

Comment: 2 possibilities. TChromium isn't getting the right data, or it isn't handling it correctly. Can you swipe a card, intercept the data from MagTek, and send it to your TChromium browser manually in order to test whether it processes?  That will help you narrow down the bug.

Comment: Maybe a third party extension is needed for chrome for the card processing? In that case TChromium wont work as it does not know about Chrome (and it's extensions)

Comment: Nope Chrome has no related third party extension, unfortunately I can't figure out why its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Question title is misleading but only because I did not understand what was happening after some investigation I was able to solve the problem.  I hope this answer might come in Handy for someone someday though its a pretty isolated problem.

So I found that the MagTek reader reads the credit card data to the field and then Sends a "Enter" button afterwards.

And the Program I am currently working with has an option where when a Enter Key is pushed it will instead send a Tab so that a user can get to the next fields by the enter key.

So the program was intercepting the MagTek reader initiated enter key and replacing it with a tab which interfered with the payment process.